# Azure Data Factory Schedule Trigger pipeline with multiple Stored Procedure in flow seems to trigger all of them

Tags: triggers, oracle-adf

[image: pipeline flow]

[image: trigger runs]

I have a pipeline with a Copy data and two Stored Proc. I set a Scheduled Trigger. In the Monitor Trigger runs, it seems that All three ran at the same time when the trigger executed. How do I ensure the triggered run follows the flow and execute the Copy data first before the Stored Proc. Thanks

Schedule Trigger set to run daily at fixed time. Expect to see only one event in Monitor Trigger runs, for the pipeline the trigger is set on.